# Show HTML hierarchy through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have task: take continuous text (html) and to present that text like normal html in `<pre>` tag with needed indentations. How can I  do it simple?

Example:

```
<!-- From -->
`<div><p>Hello World</p><ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul></div>`

<!-- To -->
`<div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

P.S. I have real text-resource and insert the result through `$(elemen).find('pre').text(result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) [Try js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)

It's a JS beautifier but works for HTML too.

2) [prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&l=html)